# How to reset parameters from AutoModelForSequenceClassification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, safe-tensors

Currently to reinitialize a model for `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`, we can do this:

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoConfig, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

m = "moussaKam/frugalscore_tiny_bert-base_bert-score"
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(m)
model_from_scratch = AutoModel(config)

model_from_scratch.save_pretrained("frugalscore_tiny_bert-from_scratch")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification(
  "frugalscore_tiny_bert-from_scratch", local_files_only=True
)
```

#### Is there some way to reinitialize the model weights without saving a new pretrained model initialized with `AutoConfig`?

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification(
  "moussaKam/frugalscore_tiny_bert-base_bert-score", 
  local_files_only=True
  reinitialize_weights=True
)
```

or something like:

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification(
  "moussaKam/frugalscore_tiny_bert-base_bert-score", 
  local_files_only=True
)

model.reinitialize_parameters()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the purpose of [from_config](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.37.1/en/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_config) (i.e. creating a model but not loading the respective weights):

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoConfig, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

m = "moussaKam/frugalscore_tiny_bert-base_bert-score"
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(m)

no_weights_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_config(config)
weights_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(m)

import torch

print(torch.allclose(no_weights_model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight,weights_model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: Thanks cronoik, that saves a many of the "proxy" reinitialized models I've been creating!